# Can I set "data" properties on a Jenkins Logstash message?

Tags: jenkins, logstash, elk

I'm sending build logs to Logstash via the logstashSend method at the end of a Jenkins declarative pipeline. The logs are being written to Logstash and I can query them in Kibana. The "data" section of the message contains what looks like a pre-configured set of Jenkins job properties. I'd like to add some properties to this set but I can't find any documentation that talks about how those properties are set.

Is there any way to add to/modify the properties in the data section of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not supported yet, but is a highly requested feature.

You can see that there is an [open issue (JENKINS-50455)](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50455?src=confmacro) for implementing this new feature.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I'd seen something about this but couldn't find it. Thought maybe I'd imagined it...

Comment: Nope. All set, Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Should be all set. Thanks.